# Find the rows associated with names in colomn and write in a file

Tags: r

I ask you about this problem, which I belive it is simple to resolve. I have this object:

```
data<-as.data.frame(data)    
colnames(data)<-c("A", "B", "C")
data

A   B   C
AA  5   6
AB  8   6
DC  5   4    
AD  3   9    
FE  2   8    
AF  4   4    
AG  2   0
```

and moreover I have a list of names:

```
common

AG    
FE    
AD
```

I want to obtain a file in which I find row associated to these names:

```
newdata
A   B   C    
AG  2   0    
FE  2   8    
AD  3   9
```

I try with dplyr R package, using this script, but it does not work.

```
library(dplyr)    
results <- data.frame()    
for (r in 1:nrow(common)) {    
    dat.query3[r] <- filter(data, C == common[r,] )    
    write(dat.query3[r],file="myfile",append=TRUE)    
    df <- data.frame(list(dat.query3[r]))
    newdata <- rbind(results, df)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use `dplyr` for this just match the names in your common vector with the first column of the data like this:

```
newdata <- data[data[,1]%in%common,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way could be as:

```
newdata <- data[data$A %in% common,]

newdata
#   A B C
#4 AD 3 9
#5 FE 2 8
#7 AG 2 0
```